# How to query CAS for all logged in users?

Tags: java, single-sign-on, cas

I am putting together an SSO system for all of our internal apps and will be using CAS. I have been asked to make a simple web app whose sole purpose in life is to monitor CAS and display a page containing the usernames of all the currently logged-in users.

I am trying to figure out the best way to query CAS for this kind of information.

I know that CAS has a concept of a `TicketRegistry` that keeps a list of all active/valid tickets; where each ticket has user information (I believe in the form of an `IPersonAttributeDao`). Perhaps there is a why to query CAS for the contents of its ticket registry, and obtain each person attribute's username info somehow?

If not the ticket registry, what would be a good way to access this info?

Comment: I guess I just need a way to access a `Principal` based on its associated `Ticket`.

Comment: Here are the [CAS 3.1 Javadocs](http://developer.jasig.org/projects/cas/cas-server-core/cas-server/cas-server-core/apidocs/) that are probably applicable to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in [CAS protocol](http://www.jasig.org/cas/protocol) that allows to query a server for the list of the currently active tickets.

I assume you are using Jasig CAS as your server. I think you could add a view, controller and domain object injected with current ticket registry and simply call TicketRegistry.getTickets() to have all Tickets (including expired ones). You will still have to call getAuthentication for the implementation of Ticket (it exists in both ServiceTicket and ServiceGrantingTicket but I could not find it in any superclass or interface), and then Authentication.getPrincipal().

I do not know if the list of PrincipalS that you will get will contains duplicates, but if I were you I would test for such duplicates.

CAS is a Spring application so the first place to look for adding this stuff should be cas-server-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/cas-servlet.xml.

I'm afraid I can't do more without knowing the exact implementation of CAS you will use.

cas-server-webapp is a spring-mvc app, so you should find a lot of information in [Spring documentation](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) - please note that as CAS 3.1 uses version 2 of Spring you should look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.3/reference/ .

The following is only a skeleton of what could be done and is untested stuff that may contains typo or other mistakes. Also, there are no interfaces, and view name is hardcoded what are not recommended practices in real world. It must be taken for what it is : a simplified skeletal example of a possible implementation.

#### Domain object (optional)

```
private TicketRegistry ticketRegistry;
public class LoggedUsersService {
    public List<what_you_want> getLoggedInUsers() {
        List<Principal> userList; // or List<Authentication> or ...
        // extract pricipal list from ticketRegistry
        ...
        return userList;
    }
    public void setTicketRegistry(TicketRegistry ticketRegistry) {
        this.ticketRegistry = ticketRegistry);
    }
}
```

It should be declared in `deployerConfigContext.xml`

```
<bean id="loggedUserService" class="path_to/LoggerUserService">
    <property name="ticketRegistry" ref="ticketRegistry"/>
</bean>
```

It is optional because you could do that stuff directly in controller ... but separation makes tests easier.

#### Controller

```
private LoggedUsersService loggedUsersService;
public class LoggedUserController implements Controller {
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        // set view name and optionaly whant you need to do
        mav.setViewName("loggedusers")
        mav.addObject("userList", loggedUserService.getLoggedInUsers());
        return mav;
    }
    public void setLoggedUsersService(LoggedUserService loggedUsersService) {
        this.loggedUsersService = loggedUsersService; 
    }
}
```

It should be declared in `cas-servlet.xml` and included in a handler mapping

```
<bean id="loggedUserController" class="path_to/LoggerUserService">
    <property name="ticketRegistry" ref="ticketRegistry"/>
</bean>
<bean id="handlerMappingC"
    ...
        <props>
...
            <prop key="/loggedUsers">loggedUsersController</prop>
        </props>
...
</bean>
```

#### View

Then in your `loggedusers.jsp`, you can access to the list of users under bean name "userList" in request scope

```
<jsp:useBean id="userList" scope="request"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Serge Ballesta! - Yes I am using JASIG CAS 3.1 (see above link for Javadocs). Furthermore I have not changed any configs in the `cas-servlet.xml` or `deployerConfigContext.xml`. If you need me to look to see what beans are being injected, please let me know what you need to see. **Can you provide a code example of what this process might look like?** Thanks again!

Comment: It looks like CAS 3.1 is a quite old version. According to Roadmap page at https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/CAS+Roadmap current version is 3.5.x since july 2012. Have you a reason to use such an old server ? It is not a problem to me, but config file may have syntax changes.